# Tomcat 7.0.27 does not work with custom tags

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl, tomcat7, jsp-tags

I'm working on making an application (developed for tomcat 5.5) to be compatible with tomcat 7 (7.0.27). The application uses both standard jstl as well as custom tags. Standard tags work fine, however I cannot get custom tags to work with tomcat 7 (they work fine in tomcat 5.5). What could be the cause of this problem?

This works:

```
<c:out value="${arrival.flt}" />
```

and this doesn't:

```
<flight:identity-flr flight="${arrival}" />
```

EDIT:

Yes, I have my taglib specified in index.jsp file:

```
<%@taglib prefix="flight" uri="path_to_tag_library/flight"%>
```

Comment: Check if have defined the taglib directive for that prefix.

Comment: Do you have this defined in your web.xml?

Comment: I have a .jar file which contains all custom tags.

Comment: What is your taglib declaration for JSTL? What version of JSTL are you using?

Comment: Hi, It's JSTL 1.0 I believe. Taglib declaration looks like this: <%@taglib prefix="flight" uri="uri:path_to_tag_library"%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution to this problem. What I didn't realize was that tomcat 5.5 contains 3 folders (lib) where .jars are stored. I only copied jars from one folder and the applciation needed libraries from common/lib folder as well. After copying them into my project's WEB-INF/lib and rebuilding the application, custom tags are now working in this application.